# java exec a java command with failure

Tags: java, runtime, exec

On Windows, I try to execute a java command (java -version for example) using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -version").

There is no errors , but the command seems to be never executed. Or JAVA is called but do nothing.

I put this command in a BAT file and try to execute Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file.bat").
I have the same bad result.

Six months before, it was OK.

Is there any RESTRICTIONS now to do that ? Only on Windows ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your code ran on Windows 6 months ago ?

Comment: How are you making the judgement that the command "seems to be never executed"? Are you seeing output? What are you seeing? Likely you have a PATH issue whereby it's not finding the correct path to "java". Try putting in the full path to java, i.e.
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -version"

Comment: hi !Yes it always run before. Even at home. But now all is wrong.I found a solution by using a detached process with a synchronized file.

Comment: check output stream and error output stream, I am not sure, but I think, that the output of version will be in output stream

Answer (score 0):

Try to send -version as a second String to the Runtime Executor. 
Additionally, you can log the OutputStream to help investigate the issue.

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java", "-version"});
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
             LOGGER.info("RuntimeProcess Printed: {}", line);
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("ERROR: {}", e);
}
```

Lastly, be mindful of the command you are running. For instance if you try to run a Unix command on a Windows machine you're going to see exceptions.

Hope this helps.